# GIMP Screenshot issue with budgie

Tags: gimp, screenshot, budgie

GIMP > File > Create > Screenshot... Does not select GIMP. Only a red animated dot is showing in the dock.

Comment: After taking the screenshot, it must switch to GIMP. Instead of this, only a red animated dot is showing in the dock.

Comment: That is strange. I don't have Budgie. I have used the screenshot feature in gimp and never seen this.